# Can we replace components used inside another component using HOC or any react pattern?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react library who's props I want to manipulate. For that I encapsulated it in a HOC.

*Example, This is the class from the library:*

```
   class Hello extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
      }
    }
```

My Simplified HOC:

```
const ReplaceHello = (props) => {
return <Hello name={props.world()} />
}
```

I am doing this to replace the "name" string field in the library with a function that does some kind of work and returns a string. Sample:-

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ReplaceHello world={function(){ return 5*3}} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

The library however has another component, which uses the original 'Hello' component, like below:

```
    class World extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <div>
{this.props.data.map(function(value){
return 
        <Hello key={value.id} name={this.props.name} />});}
        <p> Thus the story begins</p>
        </div>;
      }
    }
```

However now I am at my wits end how to either encapsulate or manipulate the World class to replace `<Hello>` with `<ReplaceHello>`. As both 'Hello' and 'World' are a part of the library I cannot change that code and I want to generate the name field based on the result of a function.

I would like to replace the `<Hello key={value.id} name={this.props.name} />` to give me the functionality `<Hello key={value.id} name={value.name} />`

Comment: How World and Hello component are connected , I mean how you are using World and Hello. If you are using World directly , simply process the value.details before sending it to World

Comment: @stack26 I have just abstracted away the actual use case, which is not as simple as you say. I know in the above example it sounds silly but for the sake of this question can we assume I do need to manipulate the "name" field in hello accept a function?

Comment: @stack26 just edited the question to present the issue betteri

Comment: it seems not possible , seeing you cannot change the library.
Main issue is its inside the map loop. Let see if  we get any answers